# ORDER BY on AVG() function in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

How to use avg() on a column and then sort in the Descending Order in Pig latin ?
For example : 
If I have some rows like below where last column (4.5,3.5,2.5,5.0) is the result of AVG() operation

```
((1,Apple),4.5)
((2,Orange),3.5)
((3,Kiwi),2.5)
((4,Banana),5.0)

My desired output is 
((4,Banana),5.0)
((1,Apple),4.5)
((2,Orange),3.5)
((3,Kiwi),2.5)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ORDER BY](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#order-by) relational operator.  For example:

```
data = LOAD 'input' using PigStorage(',') AS (key1:int,key2:chararray,val:double);

data = FOREACH (GROUP data BY (key1,key2))
  GENERATE group as key, AVG(data.val) as avg_val;

data = ORDER data BY avg_val DESC;

STORE data INTO 'output';
```

Then if this is your input:

```
1,Apple,3.5
1,Apple,5.5
2,Orange,2.5
2,Orange,4.5
3,Kiwi,1.5
3,Kiwi,3.5
4,Banana,4.0
4,Banana,6.0
```

You get this output:

```
((4,Banana),5.0)
((1,Apple),4.5)
((2,Orange),3.5)
((3,Kiwi),2.5)
```